# Rails application notify changes in local embedded system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, notify

I need to display the status of an embedded system on a webpage that updates automatically.
My idea is to use something like a thread in an infinite loop looking for changes on the system

```
loop do
  old_status = status
  status = board.request_status()
  if old_status != status
    # notify change to all connected browsers
  end
  sleep 1
end
```

and then notify the users with [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) just like in [episode 260 of railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye?view=asciicast).

I've tried using a simple Thread inside the model and also [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), but I need something that will run independent from the rails application yet still being able to communicate with it.

Does anyone have a good idea on how can I do it? I've been researching about it for the past week without success

#### Useful information:

Rails version

```
%> rails -v  
Rails 4.2.3
```

Ruby version

```
%> ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295)
```

uname -a

```
%> uname -a    
Linux Server 4.0.8-2-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Tue Jul 14 18:45:50 MDT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I'm also pretty new to rails.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use resque, it works ok-ish without rails in my experience. But why do you need independence from rails exactly? Solution can vary because of it.

Comment: I need the execution of the loop to be independent from http requests. Because it need to be running even if nobody wants to see its status and I don't see a way to do it within rails

Comment: Why not Sidekiq?  The [first Google hit for sidekiq faye](http://mycatwantstolearnrails.blogspot.com/2013/04/rails-faye-sidekiq-redis.html) seems to be what you want.

Comment: @NickVeys the biggest problem i'm facing is that the event is not generated by a http request, so it does not fall into the rails controller, instead I need to generate it by checking the status of the embedded system and then tell rails to broadcast it

Comment: Hmm, have you read up on Sidekiq?  Sidekiq has nothing to do w/your controllers.  It's a background process, running your rails application code, so you have access to your models and everything.  But you don't block requests while executing in it.  I think it's exactly what you want.  If you want to periodically check for the status, you can use cron, something like [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork), [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), or even [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) which directly ties in.

Comment: Instead of `while true do ... end` try `loop do ... end`. Likewise, it's irregular to see `then` at the end of an `if` statement. That's optional and almost always omitted.

Comment: @NickVeys I might have misunderstood the role of sidekiq, but once I create a worker to check the status, how can I initialize it?

Comment: @tadman thanks for your suggestion, I quite new to ruby so I used the notation I knew from other languages. I'll incorporate those tips into my ruby code from now on

Comment: Not sure what you mean by initialize it.  Sidekiq with a scheduling addon like Sidetiq will just run a worker periodically.  It's just Ruby code, and has access to your Rails application objects.  You can do anything in there that you could in your Rails app *except* respond to HTTP requests, which you don't want to do.  So in the worker you'd just do exactly the code you posted, minus the `loop do...` and probably plus some model object retrieval. Then add the Faye notifications.